# Как решить проблему с дупликатами?

Tags: java, android, gradle

При старте проекта пишет:

```
/.../library-0.88/res/values/values.xml:7:5-12:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.
```

Как решить данную ошибку?

Comment: у вас есть какие-то кастомные вьюхи или что-то, что используете шрифты?

Comment: Мне отключить все шрифты??

Comment: нет, просто покажите где у вас используются шрифты, может у вас где-то объявлено в проекте

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел по внимательнее. Шрифтов нету нигде. И используется только стандартный шрифт

Comment: а в этой папке `attr/font` что-то есть?

Comment: В проекте папки этой нету

Comment: а в стилях вы что-то меняли? создавали свои темы или стили?

Comment: Стили менял, но только цвет  и размер текста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107126/discussion-between-andrew-and-chilo5432).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой однажды. Две разные библиотеки хотели создать один и тот же атрибут font. Решил в лоб - скачал исходники одной из этих библиотек и переименовал там font в mfont, и добавил в проект прям исходники. Процесс может оказаться довольно муторным, так как придется найти все использования атрибута в коде, но вполне осуществимый

Comment: Я нашел примерно такую же ошибку, только у меня после обновления библиотеки такое. Пришлось остаться на старой версии